# How to slice up a Basemap?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to draw a sliced sphere like

[image: Sphere]

[This](https://gist.github.com/ilciavo/f93426527cb1fc1a4da3b87627557bab) is the code I'm using to draw the sphere.

How can I do the same with `mpl_toolkits.basemap`?